# How to draw smooth line chart with MPAndroid avoiding cubic bezier going on wrong values?

Tags: android, user-interface, charts, frontend, mpandroidchart

I'll give an example, this is my chart (**please notice that I already reduced bezier intensity to reduce the wrongness of the line**):

[image]

I would like it to be rendered this way:

[image]

*Please forgive the terrible drawn red line, I just used MS Paint to make it quick, hehe.*

I wanted my chart to look like the red line in second example, where the edge of my curve is my value and not `0.1f`x before my value point. I also noticed that when using the `xAxis` enabled, it dind't properly show my values, which where integers from 0 to 4 (inclusive), but was shown as floats like 0.9, 1.9, ..., 3.9, matching the bezier curve edges. I believe this is wrong.

For the record the bezier mode is being applied to my data set with `dataSet.mode = LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LineDataSet.Mode.HORIZONTAL_BEZIER instead of CUBIC_BEZIER should do the job.